# Modifying the range in a sub using another sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a calculator in excel. Users define themselves as one 225 built-in types and 2 calculators are then auto-populated with data for that type.

There are 10 sources of data to fill in the calculator. I have set up this data in 10 different worksheets in a 15x15 grid. The data for each type of user is stored in the same cell in each of the 10 different sheets. (For instance, if you are Type 20, the data for that result is stored in cell `"D6"` in all 10 sheets).

I am trying to figure out how to change this reference in my code so that the particular cell reference for each type is stubbed in, but I haven't been able to hit upon the right way to make this work. Example code is placed below:

```
Sub CallTypeX()
    Dim backendvalue As Range
    Set backendvalue = Range("L17")

    Call CallGeneralCode

End Sub

 Sub CallGeneralCode()
     'Call data for InsCalc, where backendvalue represents appropriate range for type
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InsCalc").Range("H18").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic2a").backendvalue.Value

     'Call data for Indicator A worksheet, where backendvalue represents appropriate range for type
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F17").Value =     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic2a").backendvalue.Value
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F18").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic3a").backendvalue.Value
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F19").Value = 0.44

     'Call data for InsCalc, where backendvalue represents appropriate range for type
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InsCalc").Range("H19").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic2a").backendvalue.Value

     'Call data for Indicator A worksheet, where backendvalue represents appropriate range for type
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F22").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic2b").backendvalue.Value
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F23").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indic3b").backendvalue.Value
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndicatorA").Range("F24").Value = 0.52

'
     'Move to Indicator B section

     [TRUNCATED CODE FOR LENGTH]
```

Basically, I am trying to figure out how to set what I am calling "backendvalue" as the appropriate range for the type without having to write out the sub I'm calling `"CallGeneralCode"` for each of my 225 types with the appropriate cell reference substituted.

I am very new to `VBA.`

Comment: If you Dim backendvalue within the CallTypeX sub, its scope is limited to that sub only and won't be visible to CallGeneralCode unless you pass it in as a parameter...

Comment: Based on what your goal is, I think the best way to do is use Named Ranges in your Calculator sheets, and use VBA to change where they points to, base on the Type. This VBA is called by Worksheet_Change event so it's automatically updated.